# How can I make the Google Home unit broadcast and read UDP datagrams?

Tags: actions-on-google

I would like to be able to say "Ok Google, turn off my TV".

The smart TV I have can be discovered on the network by broadcasting an UDP datagram. The TV will then send back an UDP datagram with its name etc. The source IP of the datagram is the IP of the TV. (Once the IP has been discovered, the TV can be turned off with a simple HTTP request, but let's ignore this step for now.)

There does not currently seem to be any APIs for UDP broadcast and receive from the Google Home unit. Am I missing something?

**Edit:** I guess I have to wait for https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/direct

Answer (score 0):

For now this is not (yet) possible. Maybe you could redirect that request to a local server running in the same network.

Just as a basic idea (I didn't check if that is actual possible):

- Register a custom callback with our own web service
- Authenticate your user

  1. If you already know the user you can send a push message to the "controller" in the local network your TV is located
  2. if you don't know the user ask the user to to setup a "push receiver" in your local network. E.g. a Android app for your device. When done execute step 1.
- Do your magic from your local network where you have access to your TV
- Profit!

Comment: Yes I probably could use a local server, but I would like a solution that works for anyone and everyone. Turns out APIs for Home Automation use cases are coming later, so I'll just wait: https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/direct

Comment: I think the request here is for the device running Google Assistant to talk directly to a local device (ex: Smart TV) and not get routed through a remote web service.

However, that only makes sense if the JavaScript "application" is running on the Google Home (or Pixel, etc) device.   If it is running remotely, then that can never happen.

So I presume the first question is where does the JavaScript run?